# Using jsonbuilder with groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to use `JsonBuilder` with Groovy and create a JSON shown below. I've tried every thing and it still gives some type of error of does not work. Can some one be able to help? Also, researched in this site as well online and did not find any clear answer. Btw, I'm a new to groovy.

Also, instead of the actual values, would like to pass variables, which has values assigned some place else.

Actually sending as a POST request. This was a SOAPUI request and changing it into groovy code

The part where "Lines" can be repeated many time like an array.

```
{     
    "GameId": 383981331,     
    "Lines": [ {             
        "GameNumber": 383981331,             
        "PeriodNumber": 0,             
        "SpreadTeam1": 4,             
        "SpreadAdj1": 106,             
        "SpreadAdj2": -116,             
        "BuySellLevel": 0,             
        "SpreadUserAdjustment": 0,         
     } ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fancy when it comes to use [`groovy.json.JsonBuilder`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) to produce a JSON output. You can pass a `Map` object to its constructor and get pretty JSON string by using `.toPrettyString()` on created object, e.g.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

String json = new JsonBuilder([
        GameId: 383981331,
        Lines: [[
                        GameNumber: 383981331,
                        PeriodNumber: 0,
                        SpreadTeam1: 4,
                        SpreadAdj1: 106,
                        SpreadAdj2: -116,
                        BuySellLevel: 0,
                        SpreadUserAdjustment: 0
                ]]
]).toPrettyString()

println json
```

#### Output

```
{
    "GameId": 383981331,
    "Lines": [
        {
            "GameNumber": 383981331,
            "PeriodNumber": 0,
            "SpreadTeam1": 4,
            "SpreadAdj1": 106,
            "SpreadAdj2": -116,
            "BuySellLevel": 0,
            "SpreadUserAdjustment": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think "[" are missing in the output. How to get them in? Also, values can be passed as variables, set some place else? Note: Updated the question.

Comment: @Nick You're right, I forgot to put the object into a list. Example updated.